# Will Android studio run on core i3 370m first gen processor?

Tags: android, android-studio

Core i3 370m 1st Gen 2cores 4threads @2.5ghz.
6GB DDR3 RAM
OS: Manjaro Linux

Can this laptop run Android studio without the emulator(I will use an Android device for that).

Is upgrading the cpu to a core i7 640m 1st gen 2cores and 4threads at 2.6 ghz recommended?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU will run it fine, not impressive though, but your ram might be a limiting factor and if you are going to be making a proper project with lots of xml and java class files that 6gb ram might be a limiting factor bottlenecking the whole system. Even though Linux is a light version OS Android Studio can still horde on ram.

**Edit Based on Comment (Cant share image there)**

yes 8 gb will get you buy but the problem is you will eventually have problems even with 8gigs later own (as you scale projects and make more complex apps) and you wont be able to upgrade your ram as maximum support of both the 370m and 640m is limited to 8gb

[image: Ram Limitation of i3 same for i7]

If I were you ill just stick with 6gigs and get myself familiar with android studio and save some money and upgrade to at least a 2th gen or higher to get that 16 gigs max capacity

**Edit 3 (posting intel ark link)**

here is the [Intel ark page link](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/details/processors.html) search for any cpu that you find in your budget range which has at least 16 gb max capacity limit (for ram)

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. So the i3 370m is fine? All I have to do is upgrade ram to 8 gigs right?

Comment: Edit: Comment on your edited answer. Will using virtual memory (swap partition) help?

Comment: Why? If I use 8GB Ram and create swap memory for 8gigs, will that be a good idea considering I use an SSD?

Comment: Just checked the swap memory will help you and that ssd is a bonus even though it will still be slower then actual memory it will get the job done, won't be very pleasant but workable.

Answer (score 0):

For running android studio You have the correct processor but it is recommended to upgrade the RAM to 8 GB as it is recommended by Google, But if you cannot than you might face OS hanging issue

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. If the processor is good to go then I will upgrade the RAM also.